# Chaging textview from another activity

Tags: android, textview, settext

I have two activities
first one have two buttons
second one have one textview

what I need is
when I click on the first button the second activity open and the textview show(hello)
when I click on the second button the second activity open and the textview show(how are you)

this is the first activity layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:scrollbars="none"
tools:context=".DailyPrayersActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        style="@style/Button_Normal"
        android:background="@drawable/btn01"
        android:onClick="hello"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        style="@style/Button_Normal"
        android:background="@drawable/btn01"
        android:onClick="hru"
        android:text="@string/hru" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

this is the java class of the first activity

```
package com.daily.morning;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);
}

public void hello(View v) {
    Intent i1 = new Intent(firstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    SecondActivity.textview.setText("Hello");
    startActivity(i1);
    finish();
}

public void hru(View v) {
    Intent i2 = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    SecondActivity.textview.setText("good morning");
    startActivity(i2);
    finish();
}

}
```

when I click on the first button or the second button the application force close

this is the logcat

```
>>09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3699)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:103)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3694)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    ... 12 more
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at com.daily.morning.FirstActivity.hello(FirstActivity.java:38)
09-06 14:26:24.054: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should call Activity and send data to that Activity:

```
Intent i2 = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i2.putExtra("key","good_morning");
startActivity(i2);
```

And in your Second ACtivity on onCreate() method:

```
Intent n = getIntent();
String mrng = n.getStringExtras("key");
textview.setText(mrng);
```

you should put like this:

```
i2.putExtra("key",getResource().getString(R.string.yourstring));
```

Add your **SecondActivity** class to your AndroidManifest file:

Ans yes may be you have not initialized your **textview**...Or not find its id..

Comment: if I want to put instead of good morning an exiseted string from strings.xml how should I use it

Comment: String msg=getResources().getString("name");

Comment: please check this file

Comment: I find the id but my fault is that I put it after
Intent n = getIntent();
String mrng = n.getStringExtras("key");
textview.setText(mrng);

so when I put it before all works fine
thank you so much

Comment: I believe the line should be 
String mrng = n.getStringExtra("key");

Answer (score 2):

As your `TextView` is in another `SecondActivity`.Firts You need to fetch it via XML through `setContentView()` and `findViewById()`, but as `FirstActivity` has already it's own
 `XML Layout`. Fetching `View` is totally wrong turn.

You need to achieve your goal by pass value in a `Bundle` from `FirstActivity` to `SecondActivity` with some `Key` and fetch it there.

Here is a snipped how you can achieve these: -

```
 public void hello(View v)
 {
  Intent i1 = new Intent(firstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
  i.putExtra("KEY",YourData); // i.putExtra("greetings", "Hello"); --> Hello is data and greeting is key to fetch from.
  startActivity(i1);
  finish();
 }
```

In SecondActivity class

You need fetch your `Bundle` which you sent from `FirstActivity` to `SecondActivity` and fetch `value` against the same `KEY` which you passed on from your `FirstActivity`.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null) 
{
String value = extras.getString("KEY"); //      String value = extras.getString("greetings"); --> which will fetch data from key greetings to value. Thus value now contains Hello.
TextView.setText(value);
 }
```

Note: Exception Thrown in your Case as you trying to call method `setText()` on `TextView` which is not even present in `FirstActivity`. That's the reason why RunTime throws `IllegalStateException`

Comment: you mean with value any text I want (hello) (how are you)

Comment: TextView.setText(hello);
or
TextView.setText("hello");

Comment: @RoyJalbout : You need to pass the value with key mapping like  `i.putExtra("greeting","How are you?")` and fetch on another activity with `String value = extras.getString("greeting");` and `TextView.setText(value);`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to read
[Observer Patter android](http://andhradroid.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/object-observer-pattern-in-android/)

Thanks this you will do what you want to do :)

Answer (score 0):

try code something like this

FirstActivity

```
public void hello(View v) {
  Intent i1 = new Intent(firstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
  i1.putExtra("msg","Hello");
  startActivity(i1);
  finish();
}

public void hru(View v) {
  Intent i2 = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
  i2.putExtra("msg","How are you ?");
  startActivity(i2);
  finish();
}
```

And in your Second ACtivity on onCreate() method:

```
textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
Intent n = getIntent();
String mrng = n.getStringExtras("msg");
textview.setText(mrng);
```

get string from strings.xml

```
 String myString=getResources().getString("STRING_NAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first class you have to change your code as:

```
public void hello(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(firstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putextra("data","Hello");    //Pass the value to the intent for another class
finish();                          //If you want to finish your current activity
startActivity(intent);

}

public void hru(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(firstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putextra("data","How are You ?"); 
finish();                          
startActivity(intent);
```

}

And in the SecondActivity class

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

//Get the value from the intent
Intent intent = getIntent();
String Msg = intent.getStringExtras("data"); //the parameter "data" here defines the same name as you have used while passing the argument to intent in first class

//Get your textView
TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textview.setText(Msg);
....

}
```